# Convert sentence to weird latin using "list comphrehension"

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I need to define a function weird_latin_from_sentence that will take a sentence string and return the weird Latin version of the sentence. You may also want to define another function called weird_latin_word that takes a single word and converts it to weird Latin. The conversion rules are:

```
1. If the word starts with a consonant then the weird Latin version is formed by moving the first letter to the end of the word and adding the string "eeoow", eg, turtle -> urtleteeoow
2. If the word starts with a non-consonant character then the weird Latin version is simply the English word followed by "meeoow", eg, egg -> eggmeeoow and 121word -> 121wordmeeoow
```

For this task, the following are consonants:

> bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ

Everything else, including numbers are non-consonants.
So far, I have been able to do this for single words. Here's my program:

```
def weird_latin_from_word(english):
    """Sub"""
    weird_latin = ""
    consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ"
    for i in range(len(english)):
            if consonants[i] == english[0][i]:
                    english[i] = english[1:] + "eeoow"
                    weird_latin = weird_latin + english

                    return (english)      
            else:
                    english[i] = english[i] + "meeoow"
                    return (english)
```

How can I write this for a sentence string? Using 'list comprehension' instead of map function

For example:

```
weird_latin = weird_latin_from_sentence("Toby likes his art")
```

Output:

```
obyteeoow ikesleeoow isheeoow artmeeoow
print(weird_latin)
```

Comment: Wait wait wait. Are we talking about weird Latin or cat Latin?

Comment: weird latin. Sorry for the typo. :)

Comment: But then why the meows?

Comment: If it makes you happy, you can change it to "wooff".  Please advise with the program syntax. :)

Comment: If it works for single words, why can't you just input a sentence, translate each word, append to the output, and print it?

Comment: Also, instead of map function, how can we implement this using 'list comprehension'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement the consonant check with the `in` operator instead. Then split the sentence into words and map to the word processing function:

```
consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ"
def weird_latin_from_word(english):
    if english[0] in consonants:
        return english[1:] + english[0] + 'eeoow'
    return english + 'meeoow'
def weird_latin_from_sentence(sentence):
    return ' '.join(weird_latin_from_word(w) for w in sentence.lower().split())
```

so that:

```
print(weird_latin_from_sentence("Toby likes his art"))
```

outputs:

```
obyteeoow ikesleeoow isheeoow artmeeoow
```

Comment: While this is useful information in the general sense, it has absolutely nothing to do with the question being asked. It could equally well be made into a comment.

Comment: But your program is not considering all words in a sentence. For example: 
    weird_latin = weird_latin_from_word("Cook me some eggs")
    print(weird_latin)

Comment: @Pamela Please use the `weird_latin_from_sentence` function in my updated answer instead.

Comment: It works now. Thanks @blhsing

Comment: Is it possible to use "List comprehension" instead of map function?

Comment: @Pamela Glad to be of help. I've updated my answer so that it uses list comprehension/generator expression instead.

Comment: I understood it now. Thanks again, blhsing.